# What is the best way to write a demo and full version of your app?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, version-control

Basically, I have an application that I plan to update for the next year or so. However, with the updates I would really like to have the source in 1 location and then have a demo build if you will? Is there a way in vb.net and visual studio to say

```
If FullVersion Then
    Do Full Version Thing
Else
    Do Demo Thing
End if
```

I dont even know what to ask really, but I hope someone can translate my request into a good lead for me to pursue the answers.

Thank you!

Comment: go through lena's reversing for newbies here http://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.17 you can't beat a craker anyway. But sure protect them from newbies :). You are creating something called crippled applications that is easy to break by just setting a bit to `true/false` at run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Conditional Compilation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ae6e432(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: If you use the "static code" approach (i.e. 1 demo app and one full both), it could look like this:

#If FULL_VER Then
Do Full version Thing
#Else
Do Demo version Thing
#End If

You define compilation constant (i.e. FULL_VER DEMO_VER) yourself when you compile.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Rhino Licensing](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-licensing) in the past which I believe supports different licensing levels such as Demo, Full, Premium etc. I just used it to support a licensed / not licensed model though. Bear in mind anything like this is crackable, but it's certainly a road block for a lot of people.